# Другой пользователь Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-7, windows-8

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Решил переустановить виндовс. До этого тоже был 10, переустановил запускаю компьютер и здесь пишет другой пользователь, не знаю как убрать помогите

Comment: Не все так просто, все учетные записи удалены. У меня аналогичная ситуация. Переустанавливал через утилиту обновления на сайте Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в систему под известным пользователем (под собой). Далее: Управление компьютером/локальные пользователи и группы/пользователи.  В Windows 10 проще всего: Пуск/Средства администрирования/Управление компьютером/локальные пользователи и группы/пользователи. Или ещё быстрее: сочетание клавиш Win+R, ввести `lusrmgr.msc`

Ищите  в списке пользователя с именем "другой пользователь" и, если есть, то нажмите на него правой кнопкой мыши и выберите удалить. (Очень часто он и сам пропадёт после нескольких перезагрузок, но не всегда).

Comment: Поле для логина на форме не напрягает? "Другой пользователь" - это не имя пользователя, а именно возможность войти под другим аккаунтом.

Answer (score 0):

1. В поле *"Имя пользователя"* ввести свой логин.
2. В поле *"Пароль"* ввести свой пароль.
3. Нажать <kbd>Enter</kbd> или кнопку входа мышкой.